# How to convert zodb object datetime to Python?

Tags: python, datetime, zodb

Below is my the dictionary object after converting the DateTime broken object

```
{'_amon': 'Apr', '_aday': 'Mon', '_hour': 10, '_pmon': 'Apr.', '_fmon': 'April', '_pday': 'Mon.', '_fday': 'Monday', '_pm': 'am', '_t': 1428915860.996431, '_minute': 4, '_micros': 1428915860996431L, '_d': 41740.37802079203, '_nearsec': 20.0, '_tz': 'GMT+1', '_month': 4, '_timezone_naive': False, '_pmhour': 10, '_year': 2015, '_second': 20.996431, '_day': 13, '_dayoffset': 1, 'time': 0.37802079202811}
```

I am unable to convert the object in DateTime format.

Answer (score 0):

[Read the documentation here](https://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/misc/datetime.html#converting-between-datetime-and-datetime)

```
from DateTime import DateTime
zope_DT = DateTime() # this is now.
python_dt = zope_DT.asdatetime() # ZODB DateTime to Python Datetime
```

Comment: I have already tried this, can you please try my question on python terminal.

Comment: import datetime 

datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(a['_t']) 

It was done by doing this.